# How do I view the mark ring?

Tags: mark-ring

Is there a command to view the entries in the mark ring, similar to listing buffers with `C-x C-b` or viewing the kill ring with the function `browse-kill-ring` or viewing the jump list (in info mode) with `L`?

It doesn't need to be bound to a key -- I don't even know of (and cannot find) any function that does this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>`C-h v mark-ring`</kbd>

<kbd>`C-h v global-mark-ring`</kbd>

A *ring* is an elisp data structure. It can be created by `make-ring` function and assigned to any variable.

> Each buffer remembers previous locations of the mark, in the “mark
>   ring”.

That “mark ring” is an elisp variable `mark-ring` that is a *buffer local variable*(each buffer has its own value of that variable).  `mark-ring` is declared in *emacs/26.1/lisp/simple.el*, and core push/pop functions operate on this variable.
To view value of `mark-ring` variable in a current buffer: <kbd>`C-h v mark-ring`</kbd>

Other packages create/use their own rings; For example *emacs/26.1/lisp/progmodes/xref.el* ("crossreference)" that jumps to source code definitions uses `xref--marker-ring` variable to contain its marker ring:

```el
(defvar xref--marker-ring (make-ring xref-marker-ring-length)
  "Ring of markers to implement the marker stack.")
```

*ggtags* uses it too.

To view value of `global-mark-ring`(not local, shared by all buffers): <kbd>`C-h v global-mark-ring`</kbd>

Comment: Hey, I'll make your answer the accepted one. Could you highlight (in some way) the two lines C-h v mark-ring and C-h v global-mark-ring? (As they're the ones that answer the question). I'll remove this comment when you've done so.

Answer (score 3):

The `helm` package offer the `M-x helm-all-mark-rings` and `M-x helm-mark-ring` to interactively browse the mark-ring (the first show both global and local mark-ring when the latter show only the local one)

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use `C-SPC` to go to any marker, choosing it using completion against the text of its line.

- With no prefix arg or a positive prefix arg `C-SPC` is just `set-mark-command`, as usual in Emacs (set the mark).
- `C-0 C-SPC` (prefix arg 0) invokes command `icicle-goto-any-marker`, which lets you choose any marker in any buffer.
- `C-- C-SPC` (negative prefix arg) invokes `icicle-goto-marker`, which lets you choose a marker in the current buffer.

Each of the go-to-marker commands is a [multi-command](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands), which means you can act on any number of completion candidates, so you can navigate among the markers that match your current input in the minibuffer (with an empty minibuffer, all markers are candidates).

`C-h f icicle-goto-marker`:

> **`icicle-goto-marker`** is an interactive Lisp function in
>   `icicles-cmd2.el`.
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar search goto icicles icicle-goto-marker`.
>
> `(icicle-goto-marker)`
>
> Go to a marker in this buffer, choosing it by the line that includes it.
>
> If [`crosshairs.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CrosshairHighlighting) is loaded, then the target position is highlighted.
>
> By default, candidates are sorted in marker order, that is, with
>   respect to their buffer positions.  Use `C-M-,` or `C-,` to change the
>   sort order.
>
> During completion you can use these keys:
>
> - `C-RET`   - Goto marker named by current completion candidate
> - `C-down`  - Goto marker named by next completion candidate
> - `C-up`    - Goto marker named by previous completion candidate
> - `C-next`  - Goto marker named by next apropos-completion candidate
> - `C-prior` - Goto marker named by previous apropos-completion candidate
> - `C-end`   - Goto marker named by next prefix-completion candidate
> - `C-home`  - Goto marker named by previous prefix-completion candidate
> - `<S-delete>` - Delete marker named by current completion candidate
>
> When candidate action and cycling are combined (e.g. `C-next`), option
>   `icicle-act-before-cycle-flag` determines which occurs first.
>
> With prefix `C-M-` instead of `C-`, the same keys (`C-M-mouse-2`,
>   `<C-M-f1>`, `C-M-down`, and so on) provide help about candidates.
>
> Use `mouse-2`, `RET`, or `S-RET` to choose a candidate as the final
>   destination, or `C-g’` to quit.  This is an Icicles command - see
>   command `icicle-mode`.
>
> See also commands `icicle-goto-any-marker` and
>   `icicle-goto-global-marker`.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote 5 years later?