# How do I clear all marks from the current buffer mark ring?

Tags: mark-ring

Newbie here, but oddly I couldn't find an answer to this by Googling.  How do I clear all marks from the current buffer?  I did find how to [view the mark ring](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47073/how-do-i-view-the-mark-ring), but not how to clear all marks from current buffer.

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
M-: (setq mark-ring  ())
```

That is, just set variable `mark-ring` to `nil`.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote?